# Graphics in SWI-Prolog: sending a location from board to (X,Y)

Tags: prolog, gesture, swi-prolog, uiswipegesturerecognizer, xpce

I'm trying to figure out how to use the "send" graphics predicates,
I'm stuck about how to scan a click from a window, and learn the location on (X,Y) and use it to put an image inside.
I just need to know which parameters are made for it in this function:

```
send(B,recogniser, click_gesture(left,'',single,
           and(message(@prolog, insert, C),     
            massage(W, destroy))
         )).
```

Comment: Are you using a UI library? I don't understand where predicate send/3 is coming from.

Comment: Ah, now I see the XPCE tag. As a general remark: XPCE is seriously outdated as a UI library/framework. Since SWI comes with great support for Web programming a Web-based UI is in many cases to be preferred.